# How do I run a custom animated bootscreen?

Tags: 11.10, themes, plymouth

I want to create a new splash theme for Ubuntu 11.10 using a volcano theme, so when it boots the volcano erupts with lava (same for shutdown). Now I have my image (png) but obviously it does not animate. I looked at the `solar` plymouth theme and I was thinking since the animation is there I can check it but no luck.

Is there a tool or a script I need to use to animate my volcano?

The image looks like this:

[image: volcanotheme]

I've already got the animated image, I'm just wondering how I can make it run at startup.

Comment: There is a step-by-step guide here (http://brej.org/blog/?p=158) - you'll need to understand C++ if you want a custom animation...

Comment: I still need someone to award this bounty to. Please, will someone make a step-by-step guide?

Comment: @fossfreedom If you don't make a guide by tommorow, I`ll have to award the bounty to aki, his answer being the most upvoted.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I Found what I need:

```
HorizontalAlignment=.25
VerticalAlignment=.5
Transition=merge-fade
TransitionDuration=.5
```

Look at these videos:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AnwFM-46fdM

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c1bwlG6G8f8

```
[Plymouth Theme]
Name=Bizcom Glow
Description=Corporate theme with pie chart boot progress followed by a glowing emerging logo
ModuleName=two-step

[two-step]
ImageDir=/lib/plymouth/themes/glow
HorizontalAlignment=.25
VerticalAlignment=.5
Transition=merge-fade
TransitionDuration=.5
```

It loads the files:

> progress-00.png to progress-32.png

and

> throbber-00.png to throbber-19.png

To create the animation.

Here's some good links:

http://blog.fpmurphy.com/2009/09/project-plymouth.html

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Plymouth

Comment: Can you expand your answer - I was particularly interested in your question as to how you were going to implement this - your answer isnt really informative...

Comment: i got the "plymouth-theme-glow" theme and it was animated and the files are simple to understand

Comment: please post it when you are done, i want it

Answer (score 11):

Hi I took a bit of a simplistic approach when they plymouth was not animated in xubuntu 11.04

First, I found out what file was doing the file calling:

`file:///lib/plymouth/themes/xubuntu-logo/xubuntu-logo.script`

I found it using catfish and searching for plymouth 
I copied the image I wanted to change to the same folder and tried out two things that worked out:

- find out what was the png that the script was calling and change the name for my image name.
- changed the name of my image so that it was the same as the script. (re named the original to *.png.old) actually i just opened the image with sudo inkscape and modified it the way I wanted.

What I was about to do for this animated one was option b but for all the different pngs that are in the folder. For something simple like a slight modification from the original it should be easy. But your volcano might be a bit more complicated but easy to try out: and low risk since you are not modifying a script.

I used inkscape to see how each part would look and hid the different png layers.

I guess it goes without saying that the easiest way to do this is to run sudo inkscape in the `file:///lib/plymouth/themes/xubuntu-logo/` folder, backup the images and modify them keeping the same name the images .

Hope it helps.

Comment: +1 good answer - I've just tidied up some formatting for you.

Comment: Thanks! yupee, i gained a privilege!I will use the formating tips you left for me in future.

Comment: ll lib/plymouth/themes/xubuntu-logo/xubuntu-logo.script
ls: cannot access lib/plymouth/themes/xubuntu-logo/xubuntu-logo.script: No such file or directory

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to install themes for plymouth through a graphical user interface is by using Zorin Splash Screen Manager. If you make your own theme, you can easily install it and switch between it and other themes using Zorin. To find many pre-made plymouth themes, see www.gnome-look.org and look under the "splash screens" category. You can also look for  other themes through google. See fossfreedom's link for how to make themes. You can download Zorin at this link:
http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Splash+Screen+Manager?content=134231

Comment: i am not looking for a tool but how to animate my custom theme thanks tho

Comment: Okay, this is still a good GUI tool to switch between splash screens though. I use it and recommend it.

Comment: Sounds interesting ... it doesnt really answer the question though.  I dont think aki's response really answers the question as well even though he has accepted his own answer :(

Comment: Yes, we still need a complete answer on this question. I haven't awarded the bounty yet and am waiting for an answer that actually answers the question. Unfortunately, I haven't seen one yet. Oh well, I'll keep hoping until the time runs out on the bounty :)

Comment: that tools is nice actually, should be nice if you can create your own theme with it

Comment: Yeah,Ubuntu needs a GUI bootsplash creator. That would be a good one to put on Ubuntu Brainstorm.

Comment: @fossfreedom: Are you still intending on making a step-by-step guide? We still need a real answer here.

Comment: Yep, please do.

Comment: Well, I have to award this bounty soon... can someone please knock together a guide? Please? I have no one to award this bounty to.

Answer (score -1):

Try [Synfig Studio](http://www.synfig.org/cms/) or [Pencil](http://www.pencil-animation.org/).

Comment: The Ops already has made the animation. He (or she) is wanting to know how to make the boot screen his animation.

Comment: Note that the Pencil site is offline and no longer an option.