# How to make an animated plymouth theme and apply it?

Tags: gnome, themes, plymouth

I know how to customize the default plymouth theme and also I know how to install other custom themes I could download from gnome-art and some websites. But I don't know how to make my own theme which has an animation included. Can anybody tell me how the pros make it? I don't want much more. Just want to know how to make a rotating loading animation theme. I just want a spinner or something like that.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/173329/what-alternatives-are-available-to-replace-the-purple-boot-splash-screen

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/84045/how-do-i-run-a-custom-animated-bootscreen?rq=1

Comment: @Mateo Its not a duplicate and that is not what I want. I know how to install the themes I can download from gnome art or some websites like that. But I want to know how do they make it. I know how to make simple image showing as boot splash. But I want to show an animated spinner or gif image at boot.

Comment: This answer includes an incredibly in-depth how-to on how to make your own - http://askubuntu.com/a/147769/47291 - so yes it is a duplicate.

Comment: @Mateo Ok . I think that helps ! Please don't downvote!